# Proper names with determiners in GF

Tags: gf

I'm trying to generate the following sentence in GF:
`Jack wants to listen to a Taylor song`
But as I can see in RGL `PN -> NP` is the only solution to get a proper name. How to get GF to output a proper noun with a determiner and an object.

Also I'm wondering why in RGL **PN** is being called proper name instead of proper noun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntactic function of *"Taylor"* in that sentence is a modifier to *"song"*. So the grouping isn't "a Taylor", but rather "a song", with Taylor as a modifier:

- a song
- a good song
- a Taylor song

This answer doesn't necessarily work in other languages than English. But there are plenty of other structures you can use straight out of RGL, like "a song by `NP`".

#### Limited set of artists

If you have a fixed set of artists, it's probably easiest to just cheat and make them into adjectives in English. Here's an example:

```hs
abstract Song = {
  flags startcat = Sentence ;
  cat
    Sentence ;
    Person ;
    Artist ;

  fun
    wantToListen : Person -> Artist -> Sentence ;
    Jack : Person ;
    Taylor, Ariana : Artist ;
}
```

For the English version, we make the lincat of `Artist` into `AP`. This works in English, because the adjectives don't inflect, so it'll just be a single string.

```hs
concrete SongEng of Song = open SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng, LexiconEng in {

  lincat
    Sentence = Utt ;
    Person = NP ;
    Artist = AP ; -- cheat in English

  lin
    -- : Person -> Artist -> Sentence ;
    wantToListen person artist =
      let artistsSong : CN = mkCN artist song_N ;
          listenToSong : VP = mkVP listen_V2 (mkNP a_Det artistsSong) ;
       in mkUtt (mkS (mkCl person want_VV listenToSong)) ;

    -- : Person
    Jack = mkNP (mkPN "Jack") ;

    -- : Artist
    Taylor = mkAP (mkA "Taylor") ;
    Ariana = mkAP (mkA "Ariana") ;
}
```

Works as intended:

```
$ gf SongEng.gf
…
Song> gt | l -treebank
Song: wantToListen Jack Ariana
SongEng: Jack wants to listen to an Ariana song

Song: wantToListen Jack Taylor
SongEng: Jack wants to listen to a Taylor song
```

Note that if your bands have an article of their own, you'll get *Jack wants to listen to a The Beatles song*.

#### Artist as modifier vs. subject

You can always make a more complex lincat for `Artist`, here's an example. We'll add `TheBeatles` as an `Artist` in the abstract syntax. I also add another function, where the artist is not just a modifier, but the subject.

```hs
abstract Song2 = Song ** {
  flags startcat = Sentence ;
  fun
    TheBeatles : Artist ;
    isGood : Artist -> Sentence ;
}
```

And here's the concrete. I'm not reusing the original SongEng, because I need to change the lincat of `Artist`.

```hs
concrete Song2Eng of Song2 = open SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng, LexiconEng in {

  lincat
    Sentence = Utt ;
    Person = NP ;
    Artist = LinArtist ; -- {independent : NP ; modifier : AP}

  lin
    -- : Person -> Artist -> Sentence ;
    wantToListen person artist =
      let artistsSong : CN = mkCN artist.modifier song_N ;
          listenToSong : VP = mkVP listen_V2 (mkNP a_Det artistsSong) ;
       in mkUtt (mkS (mkCl person want_VV listenToSong)) ;

    -- : Artist -> Sentence
    isGood artist = mkUtt (mkS (mkCl artist.independent good_A)) ;

    -- : Person
    Jack = mkNP (mkPN "Jack") ;

    -- : Artist
    Taylor = mkArtist "Taylor" ;
    Ariana = mkArtist "Ariana" ;
    TheBeatles = mkArtist "The Beatles" "Beatles" ;

  oper
    LinArtist : Type = {independent : NP ; modifier : AP} ;
    mkArtist = overload {
      mkArtist : Str -> Str -> LinArtist = \thebeatles, beatles -> {
        independent = mkNP (mkPN thebeatles) ;
        modifier = mkAP (mkA beatles)
        } ;
      mkArtist : Str -> LinArtist = \taylor -> {
        independent = mkNP (mkN taylor) ;
        modifier = mkAP (mkA taylor)
        }
      } ;
}
```

And here's the output from that.

```
Song2> gt | l
Ariana is good
Taylor is good
The Beatles is good
Jack wants to listen to an Ariana song
Jack wants to listen to a Taylor song
Jack wants to listen to a Beatles song
```

If you wanted to make "The Beatles" into plural, then we can do this. Add another overload instance of `mkArtist`, where you give it an already constructed NP. Then you can specify that "The Beatles" are, in fact, plural.

```hs
  oper
    mkArtist = overload {
      mkArtist : Str -> Str -> LinArtist = … ; -- same as before
      mkArtist : Str -> LinArtist = … ; -- same as before
      mkArtist : NP -> AP -> LinArtist = \thebeatles,beatles -> {
        independent = thebeatles ;
        modifier = beatles
        }
  lin
    TheBeatles =
      mkArtist
        (mkNP aPl_Det (mkN "The Beatles" "The Beatles"))
        (mkAP (mkA "Beatles")) ;
      } ;
```

And this gives you the following output:

```
Song2> l isGood TheBeatles 
The Beatles are good
```

#### Arbitrary strings as artists

Finally, if you want to use arbitrary strings as artists, you can use string literals. For the `independent` field, it works great: there are functions in the  [Symbolic](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/%7Ejohn/rgl-browser/#!api/Symbolic) module that take a string literal to NP.

However, for the `modifier` field, you need to go outside the API---[here are instructions](https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2019/01/26/literals-2.html#arbitrary-strings-as-modifiers) how to do it in a slightly less unsafe manner, but it's still not guaranteed to be stable, if the RGL internals ever change.

Disclaimers aside, here's the final extension.

```hs
abstract Song3 = Song2 ** {
  flags startcat = Sentence ;
  fun
    StringArtist : String -> Artist ;
}
```

And the concrete. This time we do extend Song2Eng, because there's no need to change the lincats.

```hs
concrete Song3Eng of Song3 = Song2Eng ** open SyntaxEng, LexiconEng, SymbolicEng in {
  lin
    -- : String -> Artist ;
    StringArtist string = {
      independent = symb string ; -- symb : String -> NP, from SymbolicEng
      modifier = <mkAP good_A : AP> ** {s = \\_ => string.s} -- hack
      } ;
}
```

Let's see how it works:

```
Song3> p "Jack wants to listen to a skhdgdjgfhjkdfhjsdf song"
wantToListen Jack (StringArtist "skhdgdjgfhjkdfhjsdf")

Song3> p "9ortge94yhjerh90fpersk is good"
isGood (StringArtist "9ortge94yhjerh90fpersk")
```

Just a warning: it works perfectly fine to linearise strings with spaces, so this is ok:

```
Song3> l isGood (StringArtist "Spice Girls")
Spice Girls is good
```

But you can't parse string literals with spaces.

```
Song3> p "Backstreet Boys is good"
The parser failed at token 2: "Boys"
```